# Can you identify this restaurant at this address in 2011?

Tags: france, paris, identify-this, restaurants

In August 2011, my sister and I went to a restaurant in the Champs-Élysées. I'm trying to identify which one. I have some shaky video and this photo. On the back of the menu, it looks like it is a list of addresses, hopefully other locations this restaurant was at.

[image]

I've been in Google Maps going through these addresses, but they seem to point to different restaurants. From the footage, there is some unique artwork.

[image]

[image]

And this might also help.

[image]

[image]

Can you identify the name of this restaurant?

Comment: The list of restaurants is probably the list of restaurants owned by the same group. It lists one at _123 av des Champs Elysées_ which is [Chez Clément](https://chezclement.com/)

Comment: The picture looks like good food but the reviews and the fact that it is closed is not a good sign: https://www.yelp.com/biz/chez-cl%C3%A9ment-paris-32

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using [Google Street View on the address at 123 avenue des Champs-Elysées and going back to 2011](https://goo.gl/maps/yANHeKWqXkFa2F6W8) tells us this was [Chez Clément](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chez_Cl%C3%A9ment).

A number of other locations alluded to in the Wikipedia page match the addresses on the back of the menu. None of those locations still trade under that name.

For reference, in Street View, you can click on this button:

[image]

shown at the bottom of the box in the top left corner, and you'll be able to navigate in time. Note that sometimes when you move just a bit along a road you can get different timelines.

Comment: Great feature, I had no idea! The name matches the blurry red outline in some of the photos

Comment: Scrolling through the dates on street view  it looks like it was still there (with a new awning and colour scheme) in May 2016, but the site was boarded up in 2017 and is now being redeveloped.  You get quite a bit of history from somewhere so well-travelled.  I'm more used to using Street View for roads that have only been captured once or twice ever

Comment: As an additional point of support, the font on the Chez Clément banner matches that on the menu.

Comment: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chez_Cl%C3%A9ment _The company has been in receivership since 10 December 2015._